# Launch .jar file with a relative path via jvm

Tags: java, path, jvm

So, I am in a situation where I cannot resolve a dynamic path to a fully qualified path. (ie ./file.jar cannot be translated into C:\dir\file.jar).

Is there any method in which one could launch a .jar file without needing to specify a full path?

I'd like to be able to do something along the lines of: `java.exe -magicpathargument "./" -jar program.jar "additional args"`

I've already checked -DPath, -p, and -cp. None of which have been able to properly work as intended

Comment: why not use java -jar mypath/xyz/file.jar , or whatever path compatible with your OS and shell ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not shell. It's specifically being launched via the win32 api calls through a toml file

Comment: So your actual question is how you specify the current directory with the Win32 API that you didn't name?

Comment: I mean, that could technically work, but only if you could define that with text (ie not code). I'd also like to not rely on a windows only hack, but it could be nice atleast for a starting point. I suspect the real solution is to file a bug/feature request with the project I'm using, but I figured that this might be worth the try

Comment: There is no `-magicpathargument` because the `-jar` option always works relative to the current directory when a relative path is specified and every process has a current directory. That’s not a Windows specific thing. If the project you’re using doesn’t provide control over the current directory, fixing that would be the right approach, indeed.